# OSM to DIRECTED Graph (python-igraph / networkx)

Tags: python, xml, graph, openstreetmap, networkx

I am using this python script to download OSM data and convert it to an undirected networkx graph:

https://gist.github.com/rajanski/ccf65d4f5106c2cdc70e

However,in the ideal case, I would like to generate a directed graph from it in order to refelct the directionality of the osm street network.

First of all, can you confirm that as stated  [here](https://help.openstreetmap.org/answer_link/15463/) and [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) in OSM raw xml data, the order of the nd-entries in the way is what matters for the direction?

And secondly, how would you suggest to implement the generation of a directed graph from the osm raw data, give the the above gist code snippet as a template?

many thanks!

Comment: Did you come up with something working you could share?

Comment: yeah, see my answer below

Answer (score 5):

The order of the nodes only matters if the way is tagged with *[oneway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:oneway)=yes* or *oneway=-1*. Otherwise the way is bidirectional. This applies only for vehicles of course. The only exception is *[highway=motorway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dmotorway)* which implies *oneway=yes*.

You might also be interested in the [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) wiki page. It lists two routers implemented in python, and many others.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I updated my script in order to enable directionality:

https://gist.github.com/rajanski/ccf65d4f5106c2cdc70e

Comment: Would your script be effective to generate an origin-destination cost matrix based on time for each node in a 200 node matrix?

Comment: hi @dassouki could you specify a bit more ? 200 nodes is very small for an osm dataset..